How to handle answers that look like AI generated?
A new user has posted couple of answers that look like to me that they were generated by AI. If I've understood correctly these kinds of answers are not ok here. What would be the appropriate way to handle these?

Leave a comment questioning the user?
Downvote?
Flag? Is it spam, low quality or in need of moderator intervention?
Leave them be?

Example 1
Example 2
Or am I just the only one who thinks these are AI generated?

We don't have a site-specific rule for AI generated content, but we have a help page covering the basic issues. In short, the use of AI must be disclosed, and the exact tool must be named. Otherwise it's a case of plagiarism.
If you find any violation of this rule in a post, please flag it. We have deleted many of these posts already, and we've sent warnings to individual members. In case of continued violations we will suspend the account.
Oh, and I have deleted to posts you referenced. Those are clearly AI generated content.
